# ngbSlide displays cards one on top of the other

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a carousel that displays cards. The cards are displayed one below the other instead of inside of an carousel.
I used this approach of implementation:

```
  <ngb-carousel *ngIf="announcementList">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let announcement of announcementList">
        <mat-card style="width: 500px">
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>
               <h2>{{announcement.title}}</h2>
              </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
          </mat-card>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>
```

Where anounceList is a list of announcements which I get from a database.
Does anybody have an ideea how to fix this behaviour?

First I thought that it was a problem with the *ngFor,but i tried to hardcode the values for the list and it doosent work that way eiter.